# What does the approved state for a work item signify in Team Foundation Server 2010?

Tags: tfs, scrum, tfs-workitem

For instance, when a new bug is created, I believe it enters an approved state. What does that mean? Should not it start as new, and then become approved? We are using TFS for Scrum, and try to utilize it in the best way possible.

Answer (score 7):

When using Visual Studio Scrum 1.0 process template, the intial state for Bugs and Product Backlog Items (PBI) is "New". They start with this state because it is very easy for Product Owner (PO) to discover the new work items that has been added lately to the product backlog. Bugs and PBIs move in the "approved" state when the Product Owner accept to keep them in the backlog.  Once in the backlog, the next state is "commited" when the team commit to fix the bug during a sprint.

Regarding bugs, if the bug is related with one of the commited PBI, the best practice is to require the bug to be fixed by the team as part of the ongoing sprint. Bugs are defered to another sprint only if they enhanced the commited PBI (the user story) with new behaviors.

If you are interested to add agile planning and a task board into TFS, take a look at Urban Turtle - http://urbanturtle.com. According to Microsoft, Urban Turtle is the premier Scrum tooling for TFS.

Discloser: I work with the Urban Turtle team. So do not take my words. Instead, read what Microsoft blogs said about Urban Turtle.
http://blogs.msdn.com/search/SearchResults.aspx?q=urban%20turtle&sections=3652.

Comment: @Hamish, Yes, this is why I add the discloser notice

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Mario's answer, please see [this msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731589.aspx) for Bug workflow and state transition.

Comment: The link is broken now.

Comment: It was merged with the parent article, [Scrum process template work item types and workflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj920147.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the "MSF for Agile Software 5.0" template then bugs will start out in an "active" state and then go to "resolved" and finally to "closed". In my development group an active bug is not being worked on if it is not assigned to anyone. You can find a complete set of [documentation about this template on the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380647.aspx).

If you are using the "Microsfto Visual Studio SCRUM 1.0" template that can be [downloaded from the visual studio gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/59ac03e3-df99-4776-be39-1917cbfc5d8e) then the state should be "New". The visual studio gallery has sever video tutorials from Channel 9 that will help show you the ins and outs of this template.